# What are the different applications in Adobe Creative Suite for?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, adobe-fireworks, adobe-creative-suite

So, I have never really been into design beyond a few wireframes and paper-pen sketches and have now now bought David Kadavy's book, *Design for Hackers* and am getting into design a little bit.

I am going through Adobe Creative Suite CS6. It has so many different applications and I can't seem to make out what to use for what purpose. Which program is better for doing what?

Answer (score 15):

Head over to [Adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite.html?promoid=JOLIS) and do a bit of reading regarding features.

In general:

- Photoshop = raster image editing (photographs) or digital painting (Illustration)
- Photoshop Extended = Same as Photoshop + ability to use some 3D tools and basic video editing
- Illustrator = Vector artwork (Logos, illustrations, etc.)
- Indesign = Page layout (books, manuals, brochures, etc.)
- Premier = Video editing
- Fireworks = Web editing and prototyping (will do both raster and vector but not geared for print work)
- Dreamweaver = HTML and web code layout and editing
- Audition = Sound editing
- Encore = DVD authoring
- Acrobat = PDF editing
- Flash = Dynamic web content (generally interactive video and audio)
- SpeedGrade = Video composite editing
- Prelude = File production logging tool
- After Effects = Video special effects and titling

What you use depends entirely on what any given project requires.

Comment: Good summary...

Comment: Purposefully left off Bridge because it's a utility application that you get with every other application. You can't purchase Bridge independently, you can't choose to NOT install Bridge, and you don't **NEED** Bridge for anything. It may make some tasks easier, but it's not a stand alone tool for anything.

Comment: 1. Question asked for what each piece of software in the CS is used for. That to me includes Bridge. Especially if I took the two seconds to add it to your nice list I don't know why you would deliberately remove it.
2. All of these softwares are utilities - computers in fact are utilities. I still use Notepad or Textmate more than Dreamweaver when I do web work as an example.

Comment: My answer Ryan... my choice, not yours. Been using Adobe products since version 1 (yes 1) and I have yet to use Bridge for anything. It's a pointless application.  And primarily because you get Bridge with EVERYTHING whether you want it or not (except Acrobat). You can't purchase Bridge by itself (Adobe knows it's not worth a stand alone version). Due to this it should not ever be used to weight a purchase decision. Bridge creates nothing.

Comment: Except strong feelings...

Comment: Made me laugh, e100. :) I've tried for 4 years to get Adobe to stop installing Bridge... or at least provide the option to not install it. Combined, it wastes 2GB of disk space for an app that is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Have you ever worked on a publication with upwards of 300 advertisements in it? What did you use to ensure all of the ads were correct? Do you do any photography? Have 1000s of photos? How about vector libraries?

Comment: And your answer is not solely your answer, it is a community answer and others are permitted and encouraged to improve it. Let me state the question again for you: "I am going through Adobe Creative Suite CS6. It has so many different applications and I can't seem to make out what to use for what purpose. Which program is better for doing what?"

So which program is better for digital asset management?

You can hate Bridge because you don't need it all you want Scott but its still part of the bundle, part of the question and should be part of the answer.

Comment: If you feel so strongly about it being included.. supply your own answer.. do NOT change my answer to include items I intentionally feel aren't warranted. By your logic.. I can go edit every answer on this site to fit what I, personally, feel is correct -- that is not the intent of the editing feature on the site.

Comment: I respect your right to use Bridge and recommend it all you want. It is only fair that I expect the same respect regarding my opinion of Bridge. Bridge is not the be-all-end-all of asset management. And as I've posted... you CAN NOT purchase Bridge. So it's irrelevant.

Comment: Maybve we can cover this by linking to an separate question about Bridge: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/412/how-should-adobe-bridge-be-used

Comment: Scott - I downvoted because I think your answer is incomplete now. Its not anything personal against you. As you can see in the thread e100 just posted I'm not the only one that uses Bridge. The question doesn't ask about stand-alone products it asks about the entire creative suite. I don't know why you would interject your own feelings towards this - nothing I've said is opinion and its not even about whether or not I use it. I never ever use Fireworks but if I were to answer this question I would still include it for the benefit of the community and to offer a complete answer.

Comment: As for your comment about editing - unless I missed something in the GD Meta you are incorrect. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit - please let me know if we are not following this same philosophy. Perhaps you would like to start a Meta discussion on the topic for us to discuss and define when to allow edits in our GD.SE

Answer (score 6):

Call me old school, different or just plain wrong but Photoshop should be used just for that: photo editing and retouching. Fireworks should be used for web design (the CSS exporting ability alone in Fireworks is heavily underrated much like Fireworks itself). Illustrator for, yep you guessed it: illustration work and logo's. InDesign for magazine/newspaper layouts or any print work. And lastly Premier Pro for video editing and nothing more.