# Software for Creating Yearbook (50+ Pictures/Page) Layout

Tags: software-recommendation, cs6, template-design

I'm trying to create a yearbook with each single page holding 50 to 60 pictures, depending on the class size.

I have Adobe Cloud but I don't even know what program would be best for this project. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I've tried using Photoshop, InDesign, and Lightroom and haven't had much luck getting things the way I want them.

**Which of the Adobe Cloud programs has the best tools for what I'm trying to achieve?**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use one of the Adobe products, **Photoshop**, **Illustrator** or **InDesign** are all viable options. Photoshop is great for working with pictures, Illustrator for drawing with vectors (better for illustrations, but also good for layouts) and InDesign for desktop publishing - so that would be my preferred choice. Lightroom is more of a photo editing tool (color manipulation and such).

This question will probably help you, as it explains what each of these programs do: [**What are the different applications in Adobe Creative Suite for?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-are-the-different-applications-in-adobe-creative-suite-for/7454#7454)

All of these are a bit complex to use at first (the learning curve is quite steep), so you might consider either using some other program that can handle simple layouts, or finding a tutorial that has a step-by-step guide for a project similar to yours.

[Adobe has some nice **templates**](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?l=-1&s=4&exc=19&cat=225&event=producthome) that would be a great start, as you would only need to modify the contents without touching the layout too much.