# difference between illustrator, photoshop and inDesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I know that you use Illustrator for your logo's, Photoshop for you pictures (to edit them) But for what purpose do you use inDesign? If it is for logo's and design, why does Adobe make another program when they have Illustrator already?

Comment: Also: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop is for editing bitmaps (though it's become more than that now)

Illustrator is if creating and editing vectors

Indesign is for layout of bitmaps and vectors

Simplistic but that's about it

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "layout of bitmaps and vectors"?

Comment: So you have a logo, some images and some illustrations along with some text and you want to create a book. You need a layout program such as Indesign.

Comment: No probe! There's a big overlap these days but that was the original intention with the apps