# Sharing InDesign Links between Mac & Windows

Tags: adobe-indesign

In our marketing department we have a mix of Windows & Mac computers all running Adobe CS5.5.

The problem we're having is that the Windows users will create an InDesign document with links to files such as M:\image1.jpg.  Of course when a Mac use opens this up, the links don't work because Macs have no such thing as drive letters.  We're also having the problem the other way around.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem other than making our entire department Windows or Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the drives like M:\ in your example shared on the network between the Macs and PCs? Also, since this is partly about a technical networking issue, if you don't get a good answer from the designers here, you could also try asking the tech guys at http://superuser.com

Comment: The M:\ drive is share between both the Mac & Windows machine on a windows server yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than setting up a drive letter for the network share, which *will* give you problems, add the network share(s) to your Favorites in Bridge and drag assets into your layouts from Bridge or Mini-Bridge. The paths stored in the InDesign links will be full network paths, and both sets of machines should have no problem finding them. This is the more usual InDesign workflow.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a usual workflow since Bridge is more of an irritation to most designers than a help. But that does bring up a good point: Use Bridge to help you figure out the full network path, then write your jsx to fix the links following that format so you won't have to run it again on the same links.

Comment: Designers who think Bridge is an irritation a) are wasting massive amounts of production time, and b) have never bothered to learn how to use it. Sorry to be that blunt, but designers who pointedly don't use Bridge irritate me.

Comment: You'll find quite a bit of useful information about Bridge and its uses here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/412/how-should-adobe-bridge-be-used

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly elegant but ...

You could write a jsx to do some grepping on the link paths. Once you had it set up, it could run in an instant.

Comment: Or you could fjg the matrix output with a gnuput servlet

Answer (score 2):

You could also **package** the files, which included all links and fonts in a folder.

Alternately, you could **embed** the images into the files like so:

**Select a file in the Links panel.**

Do any of the following:
Choose Embed Link in the Links panel menu.

If there are multiple instances of the file, choose Embed All Instances Of [Filename] in the Links panel menu. To embed only one instance, select it and choose Embed Link.

The file remains in the Links panel marked with the embedded-link icon .

Answer (score 2):

In our company similar situation with network links. 
As a result, I made a small script. 
Maybe this will help:

```
var doc     = app.activeDocument;
var links   = doc.links;
var counter = 0;

var PATH_FROM   = "\\Volumes\\";
var PATH_TO     = "\\\\Server\\";

for (var i = links.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (links[i].status == LinkStatus.LINK_MISSING) {

        link            = links[i];
        file_path       = link.filePath;
        new_file_path   = "none";
        new_file_path   = file_path.replace(PATH_FROM, PATH_TO);

        new_file = new File(new_file_path);
        if ( new_file.exists ) {
            link.relink(new_file);
            link.update();
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Can't find the file:\n" + new_file_path);
        }
    }
}

if ( counter > 0 ) {
    alert("Replaced " + counter + " links");
}
else {
    alert("No links replaced");
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and explain how this script is to be used?

Comment: @Benteh 
1. Change this variables with your part of file path:
`var PATH_FROM   = "\\Volumes\\";`
`var PATH_TO     = "\\\\Server\\";`

In my case I need to change MacOS-path '\Volumes\...' to Windows-path '\\Server\...'

2. Open indd-file with a lost links.

3. Run script.